# .htaccess redirect keeping the "folder" part

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I have one domain called: domain1.com
and i have another domain "linked to an host" called: domain2.com

I parked the first one to the second one

In the second one there is a folder called "fold1"

what i want is that the first one has to point to domain2.com/fold1 but without change the url. Let me show you an example.

1) If i go to www.domain1.com it has to redirect to www.domain2.com/fold1 but keeping the first domain shown.

2)Futhermore if i put in the browser, for istance :
www.domain1.com/fold2 it has to redirect to www.domain2.com/fold1/fold2

This is my .htacces but the second point doesn't work

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain1.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain1.com

RewriteRule ^(.*) http://domain2.com/fold1/ [P]
```

please help me

Comment: Did you try to add `$1` at the end of : `http://domain2.com/fold1/` ? Something like : `http://domain2.com/fold1/$1`

Comment: It works!! thank you very much :D